# JavaScript not showing red cross

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys so i am getting back search results using javascript and i am struggling to make a Red cross appear on the right hand side.

So when the user searchs through my db and the result appears i would like an X to appear to the right of it.So example :

```
Search result 1              X
```

I have made the X in CSS:

```
    #markx {
        color: Red;
        font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

My code:

```
         $(".result li").click(function(){
            var text= $(this).text();
            $('.selectedStuff').append('<li>' + text +' (selected)<span id="markx">&times;</span></li>');

         });
```

For some reason those its no appearing like i want it to in javascript. In css its fine, but obviously i want the X to appear alongside every search request that i make so later on the user can cancel that request.

Comment: in your javascript you're appending a `<span>` which is not a block-level element, and in your html you are using a `<div>` which is a block level element. Try switching your javascript to use a `<div>` or adding `display:block;` in your css. Also you will want to use a class instead of an id for "markx" because there can only be one instance of an id on a page, but it appears that you will be using multiple instances of "markx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you are overthinking this by using JS to get your dynamic X. You can achieve this in a much lighter way with CSS specificity and pseudo-selectors.

Use this:

```
.selectedStuff > div{
    width:300px;
}
.selectedStuff > div:after{
    content:" x ";
    font-family: Arial;
    color: red;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    right:-20px;
}
```

In the same fashion I added the width to the `.selectedStuff` class through the CSS, you can do that for all the other properties as well instead of hardcoding them inside the jQuery. This makes your code more maintainable.

The X is a simple letter X but if you want something better looking, use the [fontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/) library and add it as an web font icon.

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/jqMMqo)

**P.S.** I noticed in your JS you meant to produce a series of `LIs` but the code rendered `DIVs` instead when I ran it in CODEPEN. If yours produces `LIs`, just replace the `> div` my CSS above for `> li`

Comment: That is fantastic, however later on , i am going to make the X an onclick function so it can delete the search result, in case the user has got it wrong, is this possible using this method?

Comment: Sure! Now you go back to JS and make your `$('.selectedStuff > div:after').click().....remove something`. And by something, I mean retracing back to it's parent and find within it the li that needs to be deleted